# xsd restrictions not reflected in WSDL

Tags: xsd, wsdl, jax-ws

The generated WSDL at deploy time from my JAX-WS service does not reflect the restrictions specified in the associated XMLSchema .xsd file, although the generated Java class files do. I am using xjc to compile the schema.

Below are some snippets that explain in more detail:
...from the .xsd file:

```
<complexType name="AuthToken">
<all
   <element name="userName" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
    <simpleType>
      <restriction base="string">
    <pattern value="[\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{P}]+"></pattern>
       </restriction>
     </simpleType>
    </element>
....
```

from the WSDL:

```
<xs:complexType name="AuthToken">
     <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="userName" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="password" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="partnerCode" type="xs:string"/>
       </xs:all>
    ....
```

I would have expected (and want) something like this:

```
<xs:element name="username">
   <xs:simpleType>
     <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:pattern value="[\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{P}]+"/>
     </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

Am I missing some annotation or similar in my top-level Java impl file where I define the webservice function calls?  Any advice would be appreciated. I have seen several questions regarding xsd/wsdl differences but none seem to be applicable.

Thanks.